# V8 Hidden classes for two objects of the same type are not the same if property types are different

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, v8

I have read about the hidden classes in V8 and make some tests in d8 debugger shell.

```
function Vector(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

var x = new Vector(1, 2);
var y = new Vector(1, 3);
var z = new Vector(1, 'a');

print( %HaveSameMap( x, y ) ); //true
print( %HaveSameMap( x, z ) ); //false
x.b;
print( %HaveSameMap( x, z ) ); //true
print( %HaveSameMap( y, z ) ); //false
y.b;
print( %HaveSameMap( y, z ) ); //true
```

as we can see if the object property types are different they don't share their hidden class until we try to access the property in elder object which type is different. Can anyone give a clear explanation what is happening "behind the scenes", maybe it has something to do with inline caches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 developer here. In short, what's happening is that "hidden classes" store information not just about the existence of properties, but also (relatively coarse-grained) type information about their values. To avoid having too many different hidden classes, they are consolidated when objects are touched.

In your example:

```
var x = new Vector(1, 2);
var y = new Vector(1, 3);
```

Both `x` and `y` now have a hidden class `HC1` that knows *"I have a property `.b`, and its value is always a small integer (a.k.a. Smi)"*. But then this happens:

```
var z = new Vector(1, 'a');
```

So `z` needs an updated version of that hidden class, because the value of its `.b` is a string. V8 doesn't currently go as far as remembering "the value could be an integer or string"; instead it just discards the type information. So `z` gets a new hidden class `HC2` that knows *"I have a property `.b` (but I know nothing about its value, it could be anything)"*. When this hidden class `HC2` is created, `HC1` is marked as "outdated"; but to save time, no effort is made to find and update objects using `HC1`. When you run

```
x.b;
```

then V8 has to look at `x` and its hidden class `HC1` anyway, and it notices that `HC1` has been marked "outdated", so it finds the updated version `HC2` and updates `x` to use that.

Optimizing dynamic languages like JavaScript is pretty complicated ;-)

Comment: So the property type is used by hidden class, only if it's the first hidden class for that particular object layout?
`var x = new Vector(1, 'string');
var y = new Vector(1, 3);`
Here it will create HC1 for x and say that it's `x.a` will be an integer and `x.b` will be a string, but after the `y` is created it will create a new hidden class for any type of `a` and `b` properties?

Comment: Or in [this](https://pastebin.com/Ut4dyrqb) example if I get it right z should have the latest created hidden class, but it doesn't have the same with `x` after `x`'s hidden class is updated, but when I touch `z.b` it's hidden class will be updated and now they will share it.

Comment: It's not really about creation order; what you're seeing is a consequence of the fact that hidden classes are organized in a "transition tree" internally. In your first comment, the type of `a` will still be "small integer". In the pastebin, `z` at first creates a branch in the hidden class tree and assumes "`a` is an object, `b` is a small int"; after you touch both objects, they get consolidated to "both `a` and `b` could be anything". It's complicated :-)

Comment: thanks a lot! This is for the presentation in JSConf Armenia